# problems with default datetime()

Tags: sql, sql-server

I make automatic inserts to a table. To have a control. Create a [date] column:

```
[date] datetime default getdate()-1
```

The date must be from the previous day. That does it. The problem is that the time is changing to 00:00:00.

```
2021-09-04 17:44:16.303
2021-08-04 00:00:00.000 <-
```

Do you have any idea how to keep the system time and not go to 00:00:00?

Comment: It works when I try it:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2fd3efb0e9e8a2e4c74a0ca6e426daed.

Comment: Though I, personally, recommend using `DATEADD` over adding an `integer` to a `datetime`.

Comment: getdate() - 1 returns the date and time. There must be another problem in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing  good
just look on this example  :

```
select GETDATE();
select GETDATE() -1;
```

It just  -1 day from now ( include time ) :
[image]

[DbFiddleDemo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7f8d180122b47ac82eacc317fb3931b6)

Comment: I've never seen that before.  I'm looking for it in the Docs and I can't find it.  It means a whole calendar table is build in and accessible using a tally function which is really cool